# Pandas Column 0,1 into Key:Value respectively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame similar to this:

```
     0            1
0  Index       S&P 500
1  MarketCap   1712
2  Income      26
3  Sales       442
```

My end goal is to have Column 0 to be the keys in a dictionary and then Column 1 to the values (e.g. `dict = {"Index": "S&P500", "MarketCap: "1712"}`

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am quite new to Pandas/Python and have been referencing [this](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/%7Estevel/cheatsheets/Pandas%20DataFrame%20Notes_12pages.pdf) doc with no progress.

Here is the code I have at the moment (which is scraping the data):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


BASE_URL = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AMZN"
HEADER = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"}

response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=HEADER)

result = pd.read_html(response.text)
parsed = result[5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_dict`:

```
>>> parsed.set_index(0)[1].to_dict()
{'Index': 'S&P 500',
 'Market Cap': '1712.86B',
 'Income': '26.26B',
 'Sales': '457.96B',
 'Book/sh': '237.80',
 'Cash/sh': '156.81',
 'Dividend': '-',
 'Dividend %': '-',
 'Employees': '1335000',
 'Optionable': 'Yes',
 'Shortable': 'Yes',
 'Recom': '1.70'}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks again.  If you don't mind a follow up question:  Would the approach on extra columns (e.g. I need to do the same thing on columns 2,3) be similar ?

Comment: @DaeJream Yes it should work the same way just change `0` and `1` by `2` and `3`

Comment: there is no need to select indexes!

Comment: @dae-jream just do dict(parsed[[2,3]].values)

Comment: It depends on the format you want to get as outcome because `Series.to_dict()` (the use case here) and `DataFrame.to_dict()` (extract multiple columns) are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

just do:

```
dict(df.values)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={0: ["Index", "MarketCap", "Income", "Sales"], 1:["S&P 500", "1712", "26", "442"]})
dd = dict(df.values)
```

df:

```
           0        1
0      Index  S&P 500
1  MarketCap     1712
2     Income       26
3      Sales      442
```

Output:

```
{'Index': 'S&P 500', 'MarketCap': '1712', 'Income': '26', 'Sales': '442'}
```

IN ORDER TO MAKE IT WORK WITH OP DATA:

```
cols = [0,1]
df = parsed[cols]
dict(df.values)
```

Comment: Your solution raises an error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 12; 2 is required` you should consider testing it with the OP data before.

Comment: `dd = dict(parsed[[0,1]].values)` solves the problem

Comment: It works with the example given in the beginning but if you test the script mentioned below it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary and iterate over your dataframe columns `0` and `1`
and assign `0` values as keys and `1` as values

```
ans = {}
for idx in parsed.index:
    if parsed[0][idx] not in ans:
        ans[parsed[0][idx]] = parsed[1][idx]
        
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
{'Index': 'S&P 500', 'Market Cap': '1712.86B', 'Income': '26.26B', 'Sales': '457.96B', 'Book/sh': '237.80', 'Cash/sh': '156.81', 'Dividend': '-', 'Dividend %': '-', 'Employees': '1335000', 'Optionable': 'Yes', 'Shortable': 'Yes', 'Recom': '1.70'}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple options to do the same, you can try these two ways.

1. [DataFrame.iterrows()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)
2. [DataFrame.itertuples()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html)

Example:

```
 import pandas as pd
 inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':100}, {'c1':11,'c2':110}, {'c1':12,'c2':120}]
 df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
 print (df)

 #With iterrows method 

 for index, row in df.iterrows():
     print(row["c1"], row["c2"])

 #With itertuples method

 for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
     print(row.c1, row.c2)
```

Now here you can use values to create `Dict` or `List` as per your requirement.

Note: itertuples() is supposed to be faster than iterrows()